# Find limsup and liminf of a sequence

Tags: elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

From Probability through problems by Marek Capinski,Jerzy Zastawniak,:

Find $\limsup_{n \to \infty}A_n$ and $\liminf_{n \to \infty}A_n$,where

\begin{eqnarray*}
A_n &=&\left(\frac 13-\frac1{n+1},1+\frac 1{n+1}\right) \mbox{ if}\space n=1,3,5,... \\&=&\left(\frac 1{n+1},\frac 23-\frac{1}{n+1}\right) \space\mbox{ if} \space n=2,4,6,...\\ \end{eqnarray*}

We are given definition as:

$\limsup_{n \to \infty}A_n=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}\cup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$

$\liminf_{n \to \infty}A_n=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\cap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$

I am unable to use this definition to find the $\limsup_{n \to \infty}A_n$ and $\liminf_{n \to \infty}A_n$ of above sequence.Please let me know how can I get the required limits.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to characterize $\limsup A_n$ is:$$x\notin\limsup A_n\iff\{n\mid x\in A_n\}\text{ is finite}\tag1$$

A way to characterize $\liminf A_n$ is:$$x\in\liminf A_n\iff\{n\mid x\notin A_n\}\text{ is finite}\tag2$$

Observing that $$\{n\mid x\notin A_n\}\text{ is finite}\implies \{n\mid x\in A_n\}\text{ is infinite}$$ we conclude that: $$\liminf A_n\subseteq\limsup A_n$$

With tools $(1)$ and $(2)$ check out for some $x\in\mathbb R$.  This by discerning the following cases:

- $x\leq0$
- $0<x<\frac13$
- $\frac13\leq x<\frac 23$
- $\frac23\leq x<1$
- $x\geq1$

Answer (score 0):

There is another definition that might help you in this case : limsup and liminf can be interpreted as (respectively) the sup and inf of the set of adherence values. [More on that on Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior)

Here, your adherence values would be $(1/3,1)$ and $(0,2/3)$. Does that help?

Comment: You have completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: The definition of limsup and liminf given by OP does not involve any topology and it is not compatible with the definition in the Wikipedia page you have referred to.

Answer (score 0):

We can start by the $\liminf$. Let $x\in\mathbb R$. Saying that $x\in\liminf A_n$ means that there exists $N$ such that $x\in A_n$ for all $n\geqslant N$. In particular, for $n$ large enough, $x\in A_{2n}$ and $x\in A_{2n+1}$. This information give that a bound for $x$ depending on $n$. Letting $n$ going to infinity gives a bound independent on $n$ (you should get actually an interval). Then it remains to check that each element of this interval belongs to $\liminf A_n$.

For the $\limsup$, it can help to have a nice characterization of $\bigcup_{k=n}^{+\infty}A_k$ for a fixed $n$. To do so, split the union according to the indices where $k$ is odd or even.

Comment: Can you write and show me for lim inf?